# Displaying image from input tag, impossible to retrieve the data in src

Tags: javascript, html, input, src

Here i have a function that is displaying an image on my webpage. But the problem is when i try to retrieve the value of "src" (obviously i'm trying to get the data encoded in base64) i got an empty string but i can see the image on my website and also the value of src :
[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXv6k.png)

Here is my function, and the result of console.log(reader.result) is an empty string.

**HTML :**

```
<input id="avatar" type="file" onchange="previewFile()">
<img id="image" width="200px">
```

**Javascript :**

```
function previewFile() {
      var preview = document.getElementById("image");
      var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
      var reader  = new FileReader();

      reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        preview.src = reader.result;
      }, false);

      if (file) {
        var el = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
        console.log(reader.result);
    }
```

How could i get the data ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're using the `load` event but since the code is async you need to move your `console.log(..)` inside the event since it runs before the file is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why console.log outputs blank is because you are calling it before the image has loaded. Move console.log to the load function and you will see the output.

```
function previewFile() {

      var preview = document.getElementById("image");
      var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
      var reader  = new FileReader();

      reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        preview.src = reader.result;
        console.log(reader.result);
      }, false);

      if (file) {
        var el = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }


}
```

Comment: Yes but i want to see the output outside the function, how could i do that ?

Comment: Why, what are you tying to achieve?

Comment: My goal is to get the data from src to insert the image in a database.

Comment: Yes, but to do that you need to deal with the fact that FileReader is asynchronous and thus your image upload has to run after the image has loaded (that is, inside the `load` event).

Comment: just make a call to method that ajax's the image string to a serverside script which stores in the database.
reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        preview.src = reader.result;
        insertimg(reader.result);
      }, false);
function insertimage($string) {
   //ajax call the server side script to insert image into db
}